# Does JS/CSS minification help even if the files are cached?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, minify

I am well aware that a good practice in web development is to minify your JS and CSS files when you're done developing them to reduce the amount of data downloaded with each http fetch.

My question, however, is if JS and CSS file minification helps after the first page load if you're caching the files.

I have no doubt it helps the first time, but does minification also speed-up load and execution time if the file is being loaded from an on-disk cache?

Or at that point is its effect rather small. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question because it is primarily opinion based, you are completely incorrect as this question has a definitive answer that is not opinion based.

Comment: it's mostly a download-speed optimization issue and not much else

Comment: While the question is interesting, it can be answered in several ways, depending on personal experience and expectations. `..Or at that point is its effect rather small..`. This alone depends on the kind of application and the kind of used minifier and obfuscation. A minimal example would help this question and probably be also the answer at the same time, imho.

Comment: @NicoO I'm unable to provide a sample since I am pitching the idea of minifying all of our code to my boss. He wants to know the full effects before we go in and change code. The web app loads ~70 different js and css files... So I think it would help to be minified even if cached.

Comment: I was referring to @ScottMarcus. It's probably a very good idea to minify the resources as it will have a positive performance impact and is common practice. I voted to close the question as I think (only my opinion) that it can not be answered with a yes or no. Beside a performance boost minified sources have the advantage to make versioning easier. You can simply add a version number to the resulting css and js file(s) to prevent caching problems when deploying a new version of your app. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the file is cached, it will not be downloaded again, unless the page specifies a different version of the file than is already present in the cache. As such, minification helps only when the file is downloaded and not thereafter.

The minification of the files certainly could (in theory) have an impact on parsing times of user agents, but given that we are only talking about characters, there would literally have to be tens of thousands of extraneous characters before any noticeable performance degradation would be seen. So, for practical purposes, a minified file won't be processed/parsed faster in any noticeable way than a non-minified one.

Comment: I'm aware it doesn't get download again until the cache expires. I was more curious about if the lack of extra spaces and comments increases execution time in chrome. These files are being loaded in a matter of milliseconds so I'm not sure it will but if it still cuts the time down I'd like to know

Comment: @MarcFrankel Answer updated. Technical answer is possibly. Practical answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

Minification does indeed help with speed as it optimizes the files. Not too mention when you minify it is typically coupled with versioning which is even more important in my opinion. When JS and CSS is cached without versioning a user can often get stale JS and CSS which will totally break the experience if you have made any changes to those files. Ouch!